# Getting the current ip address from within a application (VC++ 2005)

Tags: visual-c++, command-line, ip-address, system

I would like to send an email from an application that contains the current ip address of the machine.

I have the email code in place and it works. I just need to add the ipaddress to the body of the email (ie I am not doing anything programmatically with the IP address).

I was hoping there was a really simple way like running ipconfig via the system command and grabbing the resultant text.

I would rather not have to open a socket.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will loop all adapters and check for the first which is up.

```
#include <afxtempl.h>
#include <afxsock.h>
#include <iphlpapi.h>

u_long GetFirstIpAddressUp(SOCKET s)
{
#define MAX_ADAPTERS    30
#pragma comment(lib, "Iphlpapi.lib")
    IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES AdapterAddresses[MAX_ADAPTERS];           
    PIP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES pAdapterAddresses = AdapterAddresses;                                              
    DWORD dwBufLen = sizeof(AdapterAddresses);
    if (GetAdaptersAddresses(AF_INET, 0, NULL, AdapterAddresses,&dwBufLen) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        do {
            if ((pAdapterAddresses->OperStatus == IfOperStatusUp))
            {
                sockaddr_in* pAdr = (sockaddr_in*)pAdapterAddresses->FirstUnicastAddress->Address.lpSockaddr;
                return pAdr->sin_addr.S_un.S_addr;
            }
        pAdapterAddresses = pAdapterAddresses->Next;
        } while(pAdapterAddresses);
    }
    return INADDR_ANY;  // No adapters are up
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use either [`gethostbyname`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms738524(VS.85).aspx) (deprecated) or the newer [`getaddrinfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms738520(VS.85).aspx). The MSDN links contain examples as well.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT: Well, it helps if i read that you are using VC++ and not c#.....**

So you can ignore my response, or maybe use it as a guide...

here ya go:

```
using System;
using System.Net;


namespace testProgram
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            String strHostName = string.Empty;
            // Getting Ip address of local machine...
            // First get the host name of local machine.
            strHostName = Dns.GetHostName();
            Console.WriteLine("Local Machine's Host Name: " + strHostName);


            // Then using host name, get the IP address list..
            IPHostEntry ipEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(strHostName);
            IPAddress[] addr = ipEntry.AddressList;

            for (int i = 0; i < addr.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("IP Address {0}: {1} ", i, addr[i].ToString());
            }
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }

}
```

this will give you all the information you need and then some, you can parse out what you need and don't need.

Answer (score 1):

I have updeted "Jason Heine" (do not know how to tag a name) code to c++. now it should work. by the way thnx to him.
So this is what I get:

```
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Net;

void main(){
  String ^strHostName = String::Empty;
  // Getting Ip address of local machine...
  // First get the host name of local machine.
  strHostName = Dns::GetHostName();
  Console::WriteLine("Local Machine's Host Name: " + strHostName);

  // Then using host name, get the IP address list..
  IPHostEntry^ ipEntry = Dns::GetHostEntry(strHostName);
  array<IPAddress^> ^addr = ipEntry->AddressList;

  for (int i = 0; i < addr->Length; i++)
  {
      Console::WriteLine("IP Address {0}: {1} ", i, addr[i]->ToString());
  }
  Console::ReadKey();
}
```

I hope this will help you.

Tested On my PC wit wifi and LAN connecten and few virtual carsds for "VMware Player" and I get 4 IPv6 and then foloved by 4 IPv4. if you need only IPv4 you could use :

```
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Net;

void main(){
  String ^strHostName = String::Empty;
  // Getting Ip address of local machine...
  // First get the host name of local machine.
  strHostName = Dns::GetHostName();
  Console::WriteLine("Local Machine's Host Name: " + strHostName);

  // Then using host name, get the IP address list..
  IPHostEntry^ ipEntry = Dns::GetHostEntry(strHostName);
  array<IPAddress^> ^addr = ipEntry->AddressList;

  for (int i = 0; i < addr->Length; i++)
  {
      if(addr[i]->ToString()->Length < 20){
          Console::WriteLine("IP Address {0}: {1} ", i, addr[i]->ToString());
      }
  }
  Console::ReadKey();
}
```

Then I get Only IPv4. just numbers start from 4. But for me it is ok. you can add a new variable to recalculate numbering :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you may need to look into winsock2.h

Answer (score 0):

Certainly getaddrinfo works in your case, but I thought I'd mention that if you every want to more than just read the ip you can use the windows [IP Helper api](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366073(VS.85).aspx) to do most of what the ipconfig utility does.